# Weird margin when using .prependTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some trouble in understanding the following behavior. I'm having a container `<div>` which contains a few *inline-block* `<div>` nodes. Example view:

[image]

Now my requirement is, to prepend new *foobar inline-block* `<div>` elements. No Problem, using jQuery -> `.prependTo()` to the rescue(applied on the parent container). Now comes the issue, the first time using `.prependTo()` "something, somewhere" creates an untrackable margin on the right side from the newly inserted element (it lookes like this to me). Example:

[image]

As you can see, only the very first element has this margin (again, I cannot track the space using Firebug/DevTools, it seems like its not there). All further insertions are just fine. Using `.insertBefore()` on the very first element also works fine and looks great. Unfortunatly I cannot use `.insertBefore()` in my particular usecase, that is why I'm asking for some heads-up here.

What do I miss ? Where comes this strange margin/spacing from ?
How to avoid it ?

Here is the **jsfiddle** playground where the above images come from:

http://jsfiddle.net/r7d6s/

I only tested on Firefox 4/5/6 so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the whitespace inside your parent `div` (i.e. line break). It gets sanitized to an ordinary space by HTML renderer. Remove it:

```
<div id="area"></div>
```